Configuring SAI Peripheral of STM32L4 to I2S -- Not Reading into the DR
I am trying to read in and output audio using the STM32L4. I input audio using the PCM1808 in 24-Bit, MSB-First, I2S mode and use an iCE40 UP5K FPGA as the clock generator. Ultimately, I will pass in audio through the FPGA and then through the MCU, however, I am trying to get the MCU audio output working by connecting it to the PCM1808.
I am trying to configure the STM32L4 SAI peripheral to be an I2S Slave Reciever in 16-bits mode, then use peripheral-to-peripheral DMA to transfer that data to the MCU DAC, where I will connect the output to a speaker. The DMA (DMA2CH1) would move the content of SAI_DR to DHR8R1 of the DAC, triggered on FIFO full.
However, I am not writing to the SAI DR (data register). How do I configure the SAI to write into the DR? Is there a configuration to have the SAI automatically transfer the bits it receives from I2S into the DR? I know for SPI I write a transaction like this:
while(!(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_RXNE));
char rec = (volatile char) SPI1->DR;

But I'm not sure how this translates to I2S in the SAI. Please Help!
Also, I am worried about the MSB/LSB ordering and the truncating of the bits. I read in 24-bits from the PCM1808 then 16-bits to the SAI and then 8-bits for the DAC. How do I ensure that the 8-bits of the DAC are the 8 MSB of the 24-bits of the PCM1808? (Granted after proof of concept I will configure DAC to 12-bits)
Finally, I2S has two channels -- left and right. Ultimately, I want to output the left channel into one speaker and the right into another speaker, using different DMA channels to DAC1 and DAC2. Any thoughts on how to scale this would be great. Currently, I am planning to scale by offsetting the DMA read address (CPAR) to be off by 16 (i.e. SAI1_Block_A->DR+16).
Finally, I am still new to the STM23L and the SAI peripheral -- Does anyone have any tips on timing, or using the Anticipated frame synchronization detection (AFSDET)?
My Code is below:
 
 #include "stm32l432xx.h"
 #include "lib/stm32L432KC.h"
 #include "lib/STM32L432KC.h"
 #include "lib/STM32L432KC_FLASH.h"
 #include "lib/STM32L432KC_GPIO.h"
 #include "lib/STM32L432KC_RCC.h"

int main(void) {

// 1. ENABLE PINS
    RCC->AHB2ENR |= (RCC_AHB2ENR_GPIOAEN | RCC_AHB2ENR_GPIOBEN | RCC_AHB2ENR_GPIOCEN); // Enable GPIOA

   // SET UP I2S PINS
    pinMode(10, GPIO_ALT);     // PA10 is DIN , "SAI_SD_A"  to AF13
    pinMode(9, GPIO_ALT);     // PA9 is LRCK/WS/"SAI_FS_A/B" to AF13
    pinMode(8, GPIO_ALT);     // PA8 BCK, "SAI_SCK_A" to AF13

   // SET TO PROPER ALTERNATIVE FUNCTION
    GPIOA->AFR[1] |= (0b1101 << GPIO_AFRH_AFSEL10_Pos); 
    GPIOA->AFR[1] |= (0b1101 << GPIO_AFRH_AFSEL9_Pos);
    GPIOA->AFR[1] |= (0b1101 << GPIO_AFRH_AFSEL8_Pos);

// 2. ENABLE PERIPHERALS IN RCC: DMA1, DAC1, TIM7, SAI
  
   RCC->AHB1ENR |= (RCC_AHB1ENR_DMA2EN);   // Enable DMA 2
   RCC->APB1ENR1 |= RCC_APB1ENR1_DAC1EN; // Enable DAC1
   
   RCC->APB2ENR |= (RCC_APB2ENR_SAI1EN); // Enable SAI1

// 3. INITIALIZE SAI to I2S
/*
|            DS = 16-bits x2      |
|    16-bit L    |    16-bit R    | <-- Frame
|     slot 0     |     slot 1     |
*/

// Disable audio block to configure registers
SAI1_Block_A->CR1 &= ~SAI_xCR1_SAIEN;

// SET DMA (pg. 1394) to perform read/write from.to SAI_xDR register
// 1. Config SAI and FIFO threshold vlvs to specify when DMA request will be launched
// 2. Config SAI DMA Channel
// 3. Enable DMA - Set DMAEN bit in SAI_xCR1 Register
// 4. Enable SAI interface

// CONFIGURE SAI_ACR1
SAI1_Block_A->CR1 |= _VAL2FLD(SAI_xCR1_MONO, 0b0); // 3. Turn off Mono Mode (set MONO to 0) set to stereo
SAI1_Block_A->CR1 |= _VAL2FLD(SAI_xCR1_CKSTR, 0b0); // 4. CKSTR: Set Clock Strobing Edge, set to 0 s.t signals received by the SAI are sampled on the SCK falling edge.
SAI1_Block_A->CR1 |= _VAL2FLD(SAI_xCR1_PRTCFG, 0b00); // 5. PRTCFG: Set to 00 for free protocol (allows us to use i2s) (set while audio block disabled)
SAI1_Block_A->CR1 |= _VAL2FLD(SAI_xCR1_LSBFIRST, 0b0); // 6. LSBFIRST: Set to 0 to transfer with MSB first
SAI1_Block_A->CR1 |= _VAL2FLD(SAI_xCR1_DS, 0b100); // 7. DS[2:0] set Data size to 111 for 32bits and 100 for 16 bits
SAI1_Block_A->CR1 |= _VAL2FLD(SAI_xCR1_MODE, 0b11); // 8. MODE: set to 11 for Slave Reciever (config while SAIx audio block off)
SAI1_Block_A->CR1 |= _VAL2FLD(SAI_xCR1_DMAEN, 0b1); // 9. DMAEN DMA Enable, set to 1 to enable DMA (MUST BE AFTER MODE BITS SET TO RECIEVER)
// CONFIGURE SAI_ACR2
SAI1_Block_A->CR2 |= _VAL2FLD(SAI_xCR2_COMP, 0b00); // 10. COMP: Set to 00: no companding algorithm
SAI1_Block_A->CR2 |= _VAL2FLD(SAI_xCR2_FTH, 0b100); // FTH: FIFO Threshold - set threshold to FIFO Full
// CONFIGURE SAI_AFRCR
SAI1_Block_A->FRCR|= _VAL2FLD(SAI_xFRCR_FSOFF, 0b1); // 1. FSOFF: FRAME SYNCHRONIZATION OFFSET, set to 1 s.t. 1: FS is asserted one bit before the first bit of the slot 0.
// SAI1_Block_A->FRCR |= _VAL2FLD(SAI_xFRCR_FSPOL, 0b1); // 2. FSPOL: FRAME SYNC POLARITY, set to 1 (rising edge)
SAI1_Block_A->FRCR |= _VAL2FLD(SAI_xFRCR_FSDEF, 0b1); // 3. FSDEF: Frame Sync Definition: set to 1 for I2S
SAI1_Block_A->FRCR |= _VAL2FLD(SAI_xFRCR_FSALL, 0b1111); // // 4. FSALL: Frame sync active level length: specify length in number of bit clock, set to 16,  (SCK) + 1 (FSALL[6:0] + 1) 
SAI1_Block_A->FRCR |= _VAL2FLD(SAI_xFRCR_FRL, 0b1111); // 5. FRL: Frame Length = FRL + 1, set to 16-bit (i think)

// CONFIGURE SAI_ASLOTR
SAI1_Block_A->SLOTR |= _VAL2FLD(SAI_xSLOTR_SLOTEN, 0b0000000000000011); // 1. SLOTEN[15:0] aligns with slot enable for 16 slots, 0 - inactive, 1 - active
SAI1_Block_A->SLOTR |= _VAL2FLD(SAI_xSLOTR_NBSLOT, 0b10); // 2. NBSLOT[3:0] number of slots in audio frame - Set to 0b10 = 2 (i think)
SAI1_Block_A->SLOTR |= _VAL2FLD(SAI_xSLOTR_SLOTSZ, 0b01); // 3. SLOTSZ - slot size - (pg. 1377) set to 0b01 (16-bit)
SAI1_Block_A->SLOTR |= _VAL2FLD(SAI_xSLOTR_FBOFF, 0b0001); // 4. FBOFF - first bit offset, set to 0b1000 = 8 to get 24 bits

// ENABLE AUDIO BLOCK
SAI1_Block_A->CR1 |= _VAL2FLD(SAI_xCR1_SAIEN, 0b1); // enable audio block SAIEN: Audio Block Enable (pg.1366)

// 4. INITIALIZE DMA2CH1 (SAI -> DAC)
   DMA2_Channel1->CCR &= ~(0xffffffff); // reset values
   DMA2_Channel1->CPAR = (uint32_t) &(SAI1_Block_A->DR); //DMA reads from SAI DR 
   DMA2_Channel1->CMAR = (uint32_t) &(DAC1->DHR8R1); // DMA places into to DAC
   DMA2_Channel1->CNDTR = 8; // Set DMA data transfer length (# of samples).
   DMA2_Channel1->CCR |= _VAL2FLD(DMA_CCR_PL, 0b10);  // set priority lvl to very high B)
   DMA2_Channel1->CCR |= _VAL2FLD(DMA_CCR_DIR, 0b0); // 
   
   DMA2_Channel1->CCR |= _VAL2FLD(DMA_CCR_MINC, 0b1); // memory increment mode enabled
   DMA1_Channel3->CCR |= _VAL2FLD(DMA_CCR_PINC, 0b1); 
   DMA2_Channel1->CCR |= _VAL2FLD(DMA_CCR_MEM2MEM, 0b1); // set to allow for peripheral-to-peripheral mode

   DMA2_Channel1->CCR |= _VAL2FLD(DMA_CCR_MSIZE, 0b00); //Memory size set to 8 bits, data size of DMA transfer in memory 
   DMA2_Channel1->CCR |= _VAL2FLD(DMA_CCR_PSIZE, 0b00); // peripheral size = 8 bits, Defines the data size of each DMA transfer to the identified peripheral. Set to 8, 0b00
   DMA2_CSELR->CSELR |= _VAL2FLD(DMA_CSELR_C1S, 0b0001); // set dma channel 1 to SAI
   DMA2_Channel1->CCR |= _VAL2FLD(DMA_CCR_EN, 0b1); 




// 7. INITIALIZE DAC - initDAC();
   DAC1->CR |= _VAL2FLD(DAC_CR_TEN1, 0b1); // DAC channel1 trigger enable
   DAC1->CR |= _VAL2FLD(DAC_CR_TSEL1, 0b010); // : DAC channel1 trigger selection to TIM7 (pg. 492)
   DAC1->MCR |= _VAL2FLD(DAC_MCR_MODE1, 0b000); // 0b000 is: DAC Channel 2 is connected to external pin with Buffer enabled
  
   DAC1->CR |= _VAL2FLD(DAC_CR_EN1, 0b1); // DAC channel powered on by setting its corresponding ENx bit in the DAC_CR register. (p. 489)


   while(1) {
   
     
   }
 }


What IDE and framework you are using? pinMode(10, GPIO_ALT); looks like Arduino code, but main() looks like you are using c.
